# Complex Excel Sheet, Duplicating w/ Python while Changing Data Reference Tab (keep formatting/formulas/etc)

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I currently have an Excel file that has two tabs, one that has a complex format (including conditional formatting / lengthy equations) that reference a second tab (using SUMIFS statements, etc) that contains data. I have to duplicate the template ~1000 times for different locations, each of which has ~2000 lines of data. Rather than storing all of the data for every location in the second tab, I'd like to subset the data in the second tab to only be the current location of interest.

Is there a way to mass duplicate Excel files while maintaining conditional formatting/etc?

When I try doing this in Python, it always messes up the conditional formatting / equations on the first tab, so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: If you use XLwings or Win32com you can move/copy sheets like as Excel Application does.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your problems and I suggest the openpyxl mailing list would be a better place for discussion.